# Getting Invalid Connection Error while making connection with PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to connect the PostgreSQL database to Power Bi. Database is third-party DB that is hosted on the Azure cloud server. I am getting the following error -

An error happened while reading data from the provider:
'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Need to form a connection between Postgre DB and powerbi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi !! I would like to create dynamic dashboard on Power Bi and for that I am making a connection between Power bi which available on my system and Backoffice DB which is 3rd part DB but hosted at our Azure Cloud space. But while connecting the two I am getting the above mentioned error. Please suggest as I am non-technical person need assistance

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Npgsql which allows .NET access to PostgresSQL.  I installed it using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio; detailed instructions are here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

You need to connect over SSL to AWS which isn't setup by default (on my Windows 10 machine anyway)

2. Download the AWS public key from here https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
3. Convert that to a certificate using https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html (convert to PKCS#7/P7B)
4. Import that certificate to the Trusted Room Certificate described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate
5. Test access from Power BI desktop using the PostgresSQL connector and it should work